# 'key' property inside component function

Tags: reagent

I have the following case (reagent + react.js):

```
(defn row [data]
   [:li {:key (:id data :class "myclass")} (:text data)])

(defn list [rows]
  (map #([row %]) rows))
```

In runtime, I can see that react.js complains about missing 'key' attribute. Is there a way to specify key from a component function. I want raw to be a separate component function, since it may become quite big, with own lifce-cycle callbacks, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. It should be:

```
(defn row [data]
  [:li {:key (:id data) :class "myclass"} (:text data)])
```

The end paranthesis should be after `data` and not `"myclass"`.

And your mapping can be rewritten as just `(map row rows)` since `row` is already a function taking one argument.

Comment: yes, of course. that was a typo, in the stackoverflow example. but still, in such case :key property was not set, and react.js complained.

Comment: That's wierd, I tried running that exact code and it works as expected, React doesn't complain. Are you sure that it's that specific list that React is complaining about? And are you sure that `(:id data)` returns a unique value for those rows?

Comment: Almost 100% sure. Spent whole evening struggling with it, some days ago.  Now I'm traveling, will check once again once I'm back.

Comment: weird, but the problem still exists. here is the gist: 

https://gist.github.com/aav/2fdb39cf461b33d086d8

it's line 99, where I generate list, and line 57, where key is set.

Comment: got it! it seems, that if write the following code:

(map row rows) 

everything works well, and react does not complain.

but, if I write like this:

(map #([row %]) rows)

the problem shows up.

Comment: Ah, of course. That's because the end result when you do `(map #([row %]) rows)` becomes `[[:li {:key (:id data) :class "myclass")} (:text data)]]` and the `key` is on the inner vector, which Reagent won't look at for the meta data. What you loose with `(map row rows)` is that `row` is called for all rows, even for unchanged rows on subsequent updates. So to get that benefit, you could set the meta data on the outer vector instead, like this: https://github.com/holmsand/reagent/blob/master/examples/todomvc/src/todomvc.cljs#L100

Comment: But what if I have something like this: `(map #(…) rows (range)` – how would the function look like so I can treat `%2` as the ID and `%1` as the argument I can pass to my function that will render the row?